# Wordpress: change user rol based in wp_usermeta value?

Tags: wordpress

I need to change the user rol when a user visit any page of my site based in the value of data in database.

In my DB in the wp_usermeta has this row:

[image]

The meta_value can take the values 1 and 0.

Then, I need to add a hook to be fired when any page of the site is loaded to run a code which will change the user role to "myCustomRole" when the 'meta_value' of 'meta_key' is '1'. Something like:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'hooker');
function hooker(){
    $id_logged_user = $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $table_name = "wp_usermeta";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE 'user_id' == $id_logged_user && 'meta_value' == 1 && 'meta_key'== 'wpuef_cid_c17'); 
      if($results) {
      $wp_user_object = new WP_User($current_user->ID);
      $wp_user_object->set_role('my_custom_role');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

init hook is better to update user role.

```php
add_action('init', 'changeUserRole');
function changeUserRole()
{
    $user_id =  get_current_user_id();
    $user_meta = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wpuef_cid_c17', true);
    if ($user_meta == 1) {
        $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
        $user->set_role( 'my_custom_role' );
    }
}
```